# Полупрозрачный градиент фонового изображения

Tags: css, css3, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли средствами CSS изменить прозрачность фонового изображения (`background-image`) линейно, при помощи градиента. Именно прозрачность, а не наложение цвета сверху, дабы получить «смешивание» наложенных друг на друга изображений с указанием положения начала (100% видимость) и положения окончания (0% видимость) градиента? Либо другие не громоздкие варианты получения схожего результата.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [the mask](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css), Luke!

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 256px; height: 256px;
}
#left {
  background: url("https://www.rwsfl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/N2-256x256.jpg");
}
#right {
  background: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/633782900077408256/F541mrSs_400x400.jpg");
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%);
}

#originalLeft {
  top: 400px;
  background: url("https://www.rwsfl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/N2-256x256.jpg");
}
#originalRight {
  top: 400px;
  left: 300px;
  background: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/633782900077408256/F541mrSs_400x400.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id='left'></div>
<div id='right'></div>
<div id='originalLeft'></div>
<div id='originalRight'></div>
```

Поддержка достаточно неплохая, но [неполная](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask) на момент ответа.

Comment: Покопавшись, можно найти реально золотые правила. Когда-то сильно удивился `Grid`-модулю, было времечко.

Comment: https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю использовать SVG для этих целей

1. Первый шаг — создаём некий квадрат который применим для маски к второму изображению.
2. В генераторе Inkscape сгенерим `filter`.
3. Применим этот `filter` к нашему квадрату.
4. Для самого высокого изображения ни каких фильтров кроме параметра `width` и `height` и для обоих изображений `preserveAspectRatio="none"`
5. Для изображения которое на половину видно применяем как маску наш `rect` и располагаем ниже чем прошлое изображение и в итоге получаем это:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 480" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image xlink:href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wmkWkRWuKe4/maxresdefault.jpg"
           preserveAspectRatio="none"
           width="100%"
           height="100%"
           x="0"
           y="0"
       />
 <image xlink:href="http://cn1.nevsedoma.com.ua/images/2011/104/4/12147000.jpg" 
           preserveAspectRatio="none"
           width="100%"
           height="100%"
           x="0"
           y="0" 
           mask="url(#mask)"/>
<defs>
 <filter
       id="filter"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB;"
       height="1.1"
       width="1.1"
       y="-0.05"
       x="-0.05">
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur907"
         result="result1"
         stdDeviation="5" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite909"
         operator="xor"
         result="result4"
         in2="result1"
         in="result1" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur911"
         result="result6"
         stdDeviation="8" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite913"
         result="result8"
         in2="SourceGraphic"
         in="result6"
         operator="atop" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite915"
         in2="result8"
         in="result6"
         result="fbSourceGraphic"
         operator="in" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id="feColorMatrix917"
         values="0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 2 0 "
         in="fbSourceGraphic"
         result="fbSourceGraphicAlpha" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur919"
         stdDeviation="2"
         in="fbSourceGraphicAlpha"
         result="result0" />
      <feSpecularLighting
         id="feSpecularLighting923"
         in="result0"
         result="result1"
         lighting-color="rgb(255,255,255)"
         surfaceScale="-5"
         specularConstant="2"
         specularExponent="25">
        <fePointLight
           id="fePointLight921"
           x="-5000"
           y="-10000"
           z="20000" />
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite925"
         in2="fbSourceGraphicAlpha"
         in="result1"
         result="result2"
         operator="in" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite927"
         in2="result2"
         in="fbSourceGraphic"
         result="result4"
         operator="arithmetic"
         k2="1"
         k3="2" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite929"
         in2="result4"
         result="result9"
         in="result4"
         operator="in" />
      <feBlend
         id="feBlend931"
         in2="result4"
         in="result9"
         mode="multiply" />
    </filter>
</defs>
  <defs> 
      <filter
       height="1.4567636"
       y="-0.2283818"
       width="1.3276783"
       x="-0.16383914"
       id="filter1"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur1003"
         stdDeviation="14.243276" />
      <feBlend
         id="feBlend1005"
         in2="BackgroundImage"
         mode="overlay" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask">
   <rect  width="350px" height="520px" x="-20px" y="-20px" style="fill:#fff;" filter="url(#filter1)" />
  </mask>
  <defs>
</svg>
```

Естественно что маски и фильтры надо располагать между тегами `defs` и тот слой что ниже на самом деле выше, это работает как `z-index` в CSS.

Не будет работать в Edge и IE.

Comment: Я конечно прошу прощения но это ни в какие ворота не лезет, вы сами видели свой градиент? Я понимаю что на него ушло хорошо так работы, но это разве что на какой-то пиксельный дизайн подойдет.

Comment: Ох, окей. Но все же куда проще и практичнее будет наложить картинки с градиентом в прозрачность.

Comment: Да я уже понял что я тормоз :D