# Плавный переход изображения в CSS

Tags: css, графика, градиент

Есть картинка снизу, где при помощи фотошопа происходит постепенный переход изображения к прозрачности.

Можно ли сделать такое на CSS?

P.S. Это не анимация, нужно статически воссоздать такое исчезновение в стилях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите ответов? Их есть у меня! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829326/275019

Comment: Без использования JS тебе не обойтись, только если на hover сделать изменение background-image. И это будет работать только при наведении,можно сделать что как только юзер смотрит на нее она меняется, уточни пожалуйста как все должно произойти

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Полупрозрачный градиент фонового изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829326/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Объясните другими словами что надо.